# After LSUIElement agent app updating core data, how can another app be notified?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

I am developing two apps. Main app is a regular cocoa application to show data in core data. The other is a LSUIElement agent which in charge of updating the data using by main app stored in core data. These two apps should be in the same bundle.

Now I have no idea how to notify the main app to refresh its view from core data, after the agent app updated data source. They share the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.

I want to use NSDistributedNotificationCenter at first. But it seems no to be efficient and elegant.

Is there any best practice for communicating between processes or applications on mac os?

Thanks for any helps or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Distributed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html).

> The Objective-C runtime supports an interprocess messaging solution
>   called “distributed objects.” This mechanism enables a Cocoa
>   application to call an object in a different Cocoa application (or a
>   different thread in the same application). The applications can even
>   be running on different computers on a network.

Comment: I think Distributed Objects is some kind of outdated tech. The linked page is latest updated in 2007-06-06. Apple may have forgotten these things too.